# After clearing a queue, delay() seems to get shorter

Tags: jquery, delay

I have an image slider and a function that fades one image in, delays for 5 seconds, then fades out.

By clicking a button which is generated via JQuery you can switch directly to a certain image. The current image is to be faded out before. After the selected image is shown, the slideshow is to go on from that point on.

Problem: The delay getting significantly shorter when I click one of the direct access buttons. I don't know why that is happening?

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var index = 0;

  var bilder=[
    ["HA_Promo_1.jpg","(a Link here)"],
    ["HA_Promo_2.jpg","(a Link here)"],
    ["HA_Promo_3.jpg","(a Link here)"],
    ["HA_Promo_4.jpg","(a Link here)"],
    ["HA_Promo_5.jpg","(a Link here)"],
    ["HA_Promo_6.jpg","(a Link here)"]
  ];

  $(bilder).each(function() {
    $("#linkleiste").append("<span class=\"klick\">" + ($(bilder).index(this)+1) + "</span>");
  });

  $(".klick").click(function() {   
    index=$(this).text();  
    $("#promo_slider").clearQueue().fadeOut(500,runIt);
  });

  function runIt() {
    $(".blink").remove();
    if(index==bilder.length) index=0;
    diesbild="<a class=\"blink\" id=\"" + "promo_a" + index + "\" href=\"" + bilder[index][1]+ "\"><img src=\"./images/" + bilder[index][0]+ "\" alt=\"\" title=\"\" /></a>";        
    index++;        
    $("#promo_slider").append(diesbild).fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut(500, runIt);
  }  
  runIt();
});
```

Comment: It seems like the queue is not being cleared as expected. I think clearQueue only clears queue items that have not yet been run. Maybe `.stop(true,true)` would work better? Syntax is: `.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )`.

Comment: I thought about that being my problem - only why should this prvent the delay from being 5 seconds? I actually tried stop(true,true) and all other variants of stop() before using clearQueue(). I now tried using stop(true, true) additionally before respectively after the clearQueue() command. No noticable effect, I'm afraid... Any other ideas?

Comment: I now put up the example in [http://gerwinmueller.de/jqtest](http://gerwinmueller.de/jqtest) - there you can see the surprising effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got better results using setTimeout() instead of delay().
Apparently, stop() does not cancel a delay.
From the documentation:

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Demonstrative snippet, below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var index = 0;
  var loopTimer;

  var bilder = [
    ["http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/1/", "(a Link here)"],
    ["http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/2/", "(a Link here)"],
    ["http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/3/", "(a Link here)"],
    ["http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/4/", "(a Link here)"],
    ["http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/5/", "(a Link here)"],
    ["http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/6/", "(a Link here)"]
  ];

  $(bilder).each(function() {
    $("#linkleiste").append("<span class=\"klick\">" + ($(bilder).index(this) + 1) + "</span>");
  });

  $(".klick").click(function() {
    clearTimeout(loopTimer);
    index = $(this).text() - 1;
    runIt();
  });

  function runIt() {
    if (index == bilder.length) index = 0;
    diesbild = "<a class=\"blink\" id=\"" + "promo_a" + index + "\" href=\"" + bilder[index][1] + "\"><img src=\"" + bilder[index][0] + "\" alt=\"\" title=\"\" />" + (index + 1) + "</a>";
    index++;
    $("#promo_slider").fadeOut(500, function() {
      $(this).html(diesbild).fadeIn(500);
      loopTimer = setTimeout(runIt, 5000);
    });
  }
  runIt();
});
```

```css
.klick {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.klick:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="linkleiste"></div>
<div id="promo_slider"><span class="blink"></span></div>
```

Here's a [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6J65/1/), too.

Comment: That works really fine - I tried messing around with setTimeout as well, but did not manage to get it to run. Thank you very much! Funny thing, though, that the delay decreases when the click function is called - you should expect it to run the full five seconds and the execute the image change due to the description. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: No problem. Before, in the runIt() function, #promoSlider was faded in and then delayed before fading out again. Since delays can't be cancelled, a new fadein-delay-fadeout cycle was being started every time you click. So, you'd end up with three or four delay cycles running at the same time, giving the impressing of the delay decreasing. It was actually multiple cycles running at once. I hope that helps.